# Unreadable cursive word on returned post card

Tags: handwriting

I wrote a postcard to a resident in India, but it came back to me with the mark written in a cursive style that I cannot read:

[image]

"P e b r" ...?

Can anyone tell me what it says?
Also, what does it mean?

I suspect that there should be something wrong in the destination address and the post office worker striked the address out with marking the reason as shown above.

Comment: Deciphering individual instances of handwriting is outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The blue writing says **Return**.  Presumably the post office was unable to deliver the letter, but they haven't stated the reason for this.